Android Billing: How to debug. Billing works on 90% of devices
My app offers three different subscriptions schemes and one inApp product.
On all my test devices ranging from Android 8 to 14 the billing library works and shows the available products accordingly (on release and debug builds locally and even installed through google play (so production version). I am not a license tester on those devices. The real environment is therefore identical on my devices.
I got reports and screenshots that on some devices the subscriptions do not load and cannot be bought. The InApp product does load and is buyable.
I cannot reproduce this and I am lost how I shall debug this as it seems a problem that is not related to how billing is set up as it works on 90% of devices.
Any advice how to deal with debugging of billing library?
